# Program continues to run despite InterruptedException

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executor

I started learning java and I am now at the concurrency chapter. After reading some stuff about concurrency I tried an example of my own.

```
public class Task implements Runnable{

public void run() {
    while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
        try {
            System.out.println("task");
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("interrupted");
        }
    }
}

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    exec.execute(new Task());
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    exec.shutdownNow();
}
```

The problem is that i was expecting to see the following output:

```
task
task
task
task
task
interrupted
```

but after I get this, the program continues printing until I close it.
So, my question is what am I doing wrong? why does the program continues printing?

Comment: have you tried `exec.shutdown()` instead of `exec.shutdownNow()`?

Comment: exec.shutdown() works even worse. it doesn't  even interrupt the thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358139/stop-an-infinite-loop-in-an-executorservice-task

Comment: Instead of just catching the interrupted exception, you should raise it again to get out of the while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The section about interrupts in the [Java tutorials about concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) explain the problem quite well:

> **The Interrupt Status Flag**
>
> The interrupt mechanism is implemented using
>   an internal flag known as the interrupt status. Invoking
>   Thread.interrupt sets this flag. When a thread checks for an interrupt
>   by invoking the static method Thread.interrupted, interrupt status is
>   cleared. The non-static isInterrupted method, which is used by one
>   thread to query the interrupt status of another, does not change the
>   interrupt status flag.
>
> *By convention, any method that exits by throwing an
>   InterruptedException clears interrupt status when it does so.* However,
>   it's always possible that interrupt status will immediately be set
>   again, by another thread invoking interrupt.

So when you catch the InterruptedException within the loop, the interrupted status is already reset and thus, the next call of Thread.interrupted() will return false, which in turn keeps the while loop running. To stop the loop, you have the following options:

- Use `break` to exit the loop
- Use `return` to exit the whole method
- Move the try-catch-block to outside the while loop (as suggested by Nathan Hughes)
- Call interrupt() on the current thread to set the interrupted flag again
- Use a separate boolean to control the loop and set that flag accordingly in the catch-block
- Make the task a recurring task by using a `ScheduledExecutorService` and dropping the loop from the run-method of your `Runnable`

Comment: there's another option: move the try-catch to outside the while loop.

Answer (score 7):

When you shutdown the executor, it tries to stop its running tasks by interrupting them. This causes an InterruptedException to be thrown, but you just swallow it and continue. You should return in your catch clause, and/or reset the interrupted status of the thread by calling `Thread.currentThread.interrupt()`, which will reset the interrupted status and exit the loop.

Answer (score 4):

You're still in the while loop, add a break or some other way out of the loop.

```
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("interrupted");
        break;
    }
```

Threading in Java is kind of a cooperative activity, you've been asked to stop, but you need to be polite enough to actually do it. This allows the thread time to tidy its affairs before its demise.

As is explained in detail by Simon and Amir, your loop termination condition is surprisingly not sufficient.

Comment: You need to use isInterrupted because interupted() clears the flag.

Answer (score 1):

"There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so if any tasks mask or fail to respond to interrupts, they may never terminate."

source : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()