# How many ways we can stop cronjob without stopping the server in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I think we can stop **cronjob** by hmc.
If except that any ways are there please answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always abort your Cronjob from HMC using (Abort Cronjob button), however your job should be an abortable job, if it's not you will not be able to stop it.

[image]

Check this tutorial on [How to Write an Abortable Job](https://www.stackextend.com/hybris/create-abortable-job-sap-hybris/).

Comment: Actually I want to know that except HMC ,any other ways are there through which we can stop cronjob?

Comment: Another solution is to try and update(with Finished state) or delete your cronjob via impex file.

Comment: I do not think that if you change the status of the cron job to Finished or Aborted will stop it.

Comment: Can you please tell the proper way then ?

Comment: The proper way is the one described in the answer above, i don't think that there is another way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can find an answer in the more global problematic of how to stop an infinite loop in a thread. (See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2358169/1140748)

Your job is launched in a dedicated Thread.

The only way you have to stop it is to use a flag that can be set from an outside object.

In your `JobPerformable` (that extends `AbstractJobPerformable`) you have to often set this block of code to check if the cron should be stopped :

```
    if (clearAbortRequestedIfNeeded(cronJobModel)) {
        LOG.error(String.format(MSG_INFO_JOB_ABORTED, cronJobModel.getCode()));
        return new PerformResult(CronJobResult.UNKNOWN, CronJobStatus.ABORTED);
    }
```

The `JobPerformable` must be "abortable". To say that put this bloc of code in the JobPerformable implementation :

```
@Override
public boolean isAbortable()
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are several ways to stop cronjob in Hybris.

**First** and **best** approach is to abort it from `HMC` (now `Backoffice Administration Cockpit`). For that to be possible cronjob has to be `abortable`. More on abortable cronjobs [here](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8be670d686691014bdbfac79c33da20e.html).

You can also abort cronjobs from `HAC` by going to `Monitoring` > `Cron Jobs`. This works more or less the same way it does in the first approach.

There are also some ways to abort/stop/finish cronjob when the first two are not available:

1. You can remove cronjob by impex import or directly on the database.
2. You can set cronjob's status to `FINISHED` by impex import or on database.
3. You can do both (1. and 2.) also by `webservice API` I believe. More on webservice API [here](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8c84b84186691014b3bcb016407a917d.html).

Last but not least, you can abort the cronjob programmatically using:

```
cronJobService.requestAbortCronJob(myCronJobModel);
```

In this case cronjob has to be `abortable` as well.

More on cronjobs [here](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8b9ce4868669101499b2f0f25ef9395f.html).

Comment: I think if the cronjob is not abortable none of those points will make it stop, (removing the cronjob is not appropriate in my opinion, i prefer restart the server rather than removing the cronJob, because the cronJob may hold some historical/interesting information, and i don't want them to be erased).

Comment: But I want know without interrupting server how can we stop cronjob ?

Answer (score 0):

run below impex in hac

```
update CronJob[batchmode=true];itemtype(code)[unique=true];active;CronJob;false
```